# Need help to format text in charts created using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

Long time lurker, first time asker. If I'm missing something let me know.

I'm using python 35 and openpyxl 2.4.0. I've generated a number of charts in an xlsx file. Snippet below:

```
# create chart for summary graph
myChart = BarChart()
myChart.type = 'col'
myChart.style = 10
myChart.title = chartTitle    # 'chartTitle' is passed to the function
myChart.y_axis.title = 'No. of WRs'
myChart.x_axis.title = 'WR assignee'
# some lines here omitted (related to charted data)
myChart.shape = 4
newSheet.add_chart(myChart, 'F1')
```

All works well, but the chart title and axis titles are 18 and 16 pt font - much too big for the chart size. I don't want to work on the chart size because I don't know in advance how many columns will be graphed - the script reads a weekly ERP dump and graphs specific results.

The openpyxl doc provides guidance on formatting cells, but none (that I can find) on text size within charts. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope it won't get you too late. After a lot of research I was able to find a way to change the font and its size from a chart segment using Openpyxl.

The size of the font is defined at the sz=1500 and this means the usual 15 font size. Using that logic 1200 is 12. The minimum is 100 and the maximum is 400000.

```
from openpyxl.chart.text import RichText
from openpyxl.drawing.text import Paragraph, ParagraphProperties, CharacterProperties, Font    

font_test = Font(typeface='Calibri')
cp = CharacterProperties(latin=font_test, sz=1500)
chart.x_axis.txPr = RichText(p=[Paragraph(pPr=ParagraphProperties(defRPr=cp), endParaRPr=cp)])
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks Leandro, your effort is greatly appreciated!